# tSQL Trigger Logic, better to have IF clause, or IN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have been trying to create triggers to lessen the client side code that needs to be written. I have written the following two tSQL triggers and they both seem to produce the same results,  I'm just wondering which one is the more ***proper*** way to do it. I'm using SQL Server 2012 if that makes any difference.

i.e.

- which one uses less resources
- executes faster
- is more secure against attacks
- *etc...*

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProductGroup_INSERT_GroupMap
    ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]
    After INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    if (
           select count([inserted].[groupID]) 
           from [inserted] 
           where [inserted].[groupID] = 1
       ) = 0
    begin
        insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[GroupMap]([parentGroupID], [childGroupID])
        select  1, [inserted].[groupID]
        from [inserted]
    end
END
GO
```

---

### OR

---

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProductGroup_INSERT_GroupMap
    ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]
    After INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[GroupMap]([parentGroupID], [childGroupID])
    select  1, [inserted].[groupID]
    from [inserted]
    Where[inserted].[groupID] in 
        (
            select [inserted].[groupID] 
            from [inserted] 
            where [inserted].[groupID] <> 1
        )
END
GO
```

---

### UPDATE:

Based on some of the comments here are the inserts I am using. The GroupMap table has the same results no matter which trigger I use.

```sql
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('root', 'The root of all groups')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('orphans', 'This is where the members of deleted groups go')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('SMGMT', 'Support Management')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('ST1', 'Support Tier 1')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('ST2', ' Support Tier 2')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('ST3', 'Support Tier 3')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('SaaSMGMT', 'Express Management')
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) values ('SaaSSup', 'Support Express')
```

Comment: You do realise that these two triggers behave differently, right? (what if there are 2 rows in `inserted`, one for `[groupID]` 1 and one for `[groupID]` 2)

Comment: Does it really do the same thing ? You don't insert anything in first version if there's a groupID = 1 in inserted. You insert something for all groupId <> 1 from inserted in second version...

Comment: I added the inserts to the end of the question.

Comment: @BrandonB. The problem is not what you insert. The problem is that your 2 triggers don't do the same thing. And that different thing depends on what's in your `[inserted]` table.

Comment: Then I don't understand, I thought the [inserted] table was a resident table in memory that SQL creates temporarily on the insert call to a table. So the inserted table would contain the data from my `insert into ...` query, correct?

Comment: @BrandonB maybe what you're missing is that `[inserted]` can theoretically have multiple rows. Thinking about SQL a single row at a time can lead to unforeseen problems later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a comment is a bit too small to put this example in, I'm going to put it in an answer. The reason why people say your triggers are functionally different is that, although your test insert row by row, a trigger will also fire when you insert multiple rows into the table in one single operation. Based on your examples you could try the following:

```
insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]([groupName], [groupDescription]) 
SELECT 'root', 'The root of all groups'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'orphans', 'This is where the members of deleted groups go'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SMGMT', 'Support Management'
```

When doing this query the `inserted` table will hold 3 rows and (depending on the data) the result of the 2 trigger-code-examples might give different results.

Don't worry, this is a common misconception. The rule of thumb with SQL is to always think in record-sets, never in 'a single record with fields'.

---

As for your question (yes, I'm going for a real answer =)

I would suggest a variation on the second one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_ProductGroup_INSERT_GroupMap
    ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[ProductGroup]
    After INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    insert into [qmgmt].[dbo].[GroupMap]([parentGroupID], [childGroupID])
    select  1, [inserted].[groupID]
    from [inserted]
   where [inserted].[groupID] <> 1        
END
```

This way the server only needs to run over `inserted` once, decide which records to 'keep' and then store them right-away into the destination table.

The question now is, if this does what you want it to do...

Comment: I especially like that you suggest testing with multiple row inserts. It is irresponsible to create a trigger and not test this way.